# In the IPython terminal, help(object) brings up a colored man page in a "less" window. Can help() also have interaction in jupyter qtconsole/notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, qtconsole

I was wondering if more interactive `help(object)` pages can be generated in `qtconsole` or `notebook`, like the `ipython` terminal console and the builtin `python` command-line tool. For example, some temporary popup encompassing the Qt window/browser tab (respectively) that can be scrolled and searched.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython provides its own introspection/help tools with `?`, so if you do `object?`, you should get similar output to `help(object)`, and it will go into a pager area in current versions.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Are there any other `help` tools in a similar vein, or is this pretty much it?

Comment: Be sure to learn the shift-Tab shortcut in jupyterlab for bringing up help for any item under the cursor